edit <head> in woocommerce page
WooCommerce how to check if page is_shop() in functions.php?
how I can edit  meta title and description , by php function
just in shop pages (vendor and products page), wordpress website
<head>
if( is_shop() ) :

<meta name="description" content="<?php   echo "data";  ?>">
  <meta name="keywords" content="<?php   echo "data";  ?>">
  <meta name="author" content="<?php   echo "data";  ?>">

endif;
</head>

